# Animating custom UIView from off screen make its subviews not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I created a small custom UIView with a UILabel and a UIButton, this custom view is a banner to display at the top of the current view controller.

I load the view layout from a nib file and use a method from the custom view to display it with an animation, and the view will hide after a specific amount of time. Like this.

```
- (void)displayBannerInViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
{
  CGFloat originY = 0;
  if (vc.navigationController != nil) {
    originY += 20 + vc.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height - self.bounds.size.height;
  }
  self.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                      originY,
                      [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,
                      self.bounds.size.height);

  if (vc.navigationController != nil) {
    [vc.navigationController.view insertSubview:self atIndex:1];
  } else {
    [vc.view.window insertSubview:self atIndex:1];
  }

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.frame = CGRectOffset(self.frame, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:self.duration options:0 animations:^{
      self.frame = CGRectOffset(self.frame, 0, -self.bounds.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
      if (finished) {
        [self removeFromSuperview];
      }
    }];
  }];
}
```

I set the action for the button inside the banner with this

```
[self.actionButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(executeActionBlock)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

After animation showing the banner, and before is hidden, no matter how many times I tap on the button, the `executeActionBlock` method is never called.

I made a test setting the initial frame of the banner to origin (0, 0) and without animation and then the button worked fine. So, I don't know if a problem of the animation or because the original frame of the banner is in a non visible position. BTW, is important for the banner to not be visible because on the app is showing from under the navigation bar.

Thanks

Comment: you are removing the view from superview at the end no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems I should keep looking more because I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825241/ios-animation-not-responding) with the same problem. I tried the solution there and now is working.

The problem is that linking animations is not a good idea for user interaction so I used a NSTimer instead, like this.

```
- (void)displayBannerInViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
{
  CGFloat originY = 0;
  if (vc.navigationController != nil) {
    originY += 20 + vc.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height - self.bounds.size.height;
  }
  self.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                          originY,
                          [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,
                          self.bounds.size.height);

  if (vc.navigationController != nil) {
    [vc.navigationController.view insertSubview:self atIndex:1];
  } else {
    [vc.view.window insertSubview:self atIndex:1];
  }

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.frame = CGRectOffset(self.frame, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.duration target:self selector:@selector(hideBanner) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
  }];
}

- (void)hideBanner
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.frame = CGRectOffset(self.frame, 0, -self.bounds.size.height);
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
      [self removeFromSuperview];
    }
  }];
}
```

And now works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You've written your code so that you run a series of animations, where the view is on-screen during the delay of the last animation. By default user interaction is disabled on views while they are being animated. Try passing UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction in options for all your nested animations.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/uiviewanimationoptionallowuserinteraction?language=objc